# Cutting a slot in a PCB using a hand file for a USB connector - are the planes exposed and shorting with the connector?

Tags: pcb, usb, soldering

I'm making a HID keyboard which connects through micro-usb. Unfortunately I made an error in the PCB design and missed including a slot for the [usb connector](https://sg.rs-online.com/web/p/micro-usb-connectors/8967419/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E525353746F636B4E756D626572266C753D656E266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C26706D3D5E2828282872737C5253295B205D3F293F285C647B337D5B5C2D5C735D3F5C647B332C347D5B705061415D3F29297C283235285C647B387D7C5C647B317D5C2D5C647B377D2929292426706F3D3126736E3D592673723D2673743D52535F53544F434B5F4E554D4245522677633D4E4F4E45267573743D3839362D37343139267374613D3839363734313926&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D) to fit in.

Being the enterprising DIY hacker that I am, I used a hand file, [like this one](https://www.axminster.co.uk/faithfull-hand-bastard-cut-engineers-file-150mm-6in-118532), to cut out the slot and then house the USB connector snugly within it. Here's an image of the finished connector:

[image]

I assembled 2 boards and both of them have weird connectivity issues with the device working sometimes, but most times just failing as a malfunction.

The USB port's outer housing is grounded. My question is, is it possible that by filing, I exposed the ground plane and the VDD plane and now the USB connector is shorting with it, thus causing the device malfunction?

EDIT: Here's an image of the PCB layout. Have marked the USB port and the De-coupling caps.

[image]

Comment: Get a DVM and prove your theory.

Comment: @Andyaka - Whats a DVM? Voltmeter?

Comment: Digital volt meter.

Comment: Yes.  smearing of copper planes or traces is quite common when sawing or drilling through a PCB, unless you know what your doing.  One key to success is very sharp tools (i.e. drill bits) and going slow.

Comment: @Andyaka - I tried with a multimeter and didn't see anything weird. Maybe I'll try it with an oscilloscope and see, it's a good idea.

Comment: @SteveSh - Thanks, I'll get some new boards printed if this is a possible cause for the issue.

Comment: Would it be difficult to unsolder the 4 connections to the outer housing? Best try and fix what you have rather than carry an unforeseen error to a new design.

Comment: @Andyaka - problem is that the entire housing is made of metal. I don't know if there's an easy way to say for sure that there isn't any contact being made with the planes.

Comment: Case in point.  A number of years ago, we had to drill through a board that contained power (+5V) and GND planes to effect a change.  This was done by our manufacturing operations.  They were careful & followed all procedures.  Even with that, some copper smear created a low-resistance (not a dead short) between +5V and GND.  The excess current was not enough to cause the PS to current limit (200A supply), but did heat up the partial short so that over time, excessive heat caused the board to catch fire, or at least discolor from the heat.  The short did not burn itself open.

Comment: In my experience, the kind of USB connectivity issues you describe are often caused by bad PCB layout - particularly of the USB D+/D- signal lines. Can you show us what your layout looks like between the connector and your USB IC?

Comment: @SteveSh - Wow, I'm amazed that you were able to track the error to the hole that was drilled. Must have been really challenging to find that. Thanks for sharing, that suggests that no matter what, cutting a notch with a hand file has a high likelihood of being a pain.

Comment: @brhans - Have updated my post with an image of the PCB layout, do you think there's glaring errors?

Comment: @Plasty Grove - Not really.  The odor and burned area of the board were dead giveaways!

Comment: Make the notch you cut for the connector noticeable wider, so there is no chance of the connector touchiing the internal planes.  If you re-do the board with a notch for the connector, keep the internal planes away from the edges of the cut-out so there will be no chance of shorts between the connector and internal planes.

Comment: @PeterBennett - I can't cut the notch any wider without cutting through the mounting holes. Good call on keeping internal planes away from the cut-out, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Spacing of your USB traces is a bit inconsistent and I'd try to keep other unrelated signals away from them. The decoupling caps aren't doing any good at all over there on the side by themselves - each one needs to be right next to a power pin pair on the MCU.

Comment: @brhans - Thanks for the suggestions. Just started reading on PCB guidelines for USB and it's a load of info I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Several potential issues exist that I can see.

Firstly, your "decoupling caps" should be as close to the pins they are inteded to decouple (usually the IC power pins). This can cause all sorts of weird behaviour in digital circuits.

Your D+/D- diff pair is not routed with constant spacing, which could cause signal integrity problems due to impedance mismatch. Although if its a low speed device that is much more forgiving.

A third thing, in the photo of your connector, there appears to be a short between one of the data lines and the ID pin. If the cable shorts ID to ground that would cause the data line to get shorted to ground. Check your soldering, reheat the joints with a bit of flux and examine under a magnifying glass or microscope. You can also use a DMM to probe for continuity to check for shorts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've re-soldered the usb connector pins, so there wasn't any shorting with the ID pin. Also assembled a second board which has the same issue. Noted on the decoupling caps, I could update the design to put it as close as possible to the IC pins. Would it make sense to have a few placed close to the USB connector as well? Also, do you think it would make sense to have the USB connector much closer to the MCU?

Comment: @PlastyGrove putting the MCU closer to the USB port would be a good idea in terms of routing - I try to keep components clumped together to minimise the length of any fast signals. Slow signals like buttons and LEDs are non-critical so can be much longer. In doing so, I'd also arrange the MCU crystal to be placed as symmetrically as possible close to the XTAL pins.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good advice! I'll re-work the design to put the USB and crystal first before routing the other components. Do you think a 2 layer board is okay in this case? I've been seeing a lot of material online that suggests having 4 layers for usb designs. Would it be okay if I keep the USB uninterrupted by any other traces and really close to the MCU and keep the 2 layers?

Comment: USB HS seems to require 4 layers, but my MCU only supports FS, so 2 layers should be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "filtering" on your usb port. On my STM32F's I usually use 22 ohm resistors like they do on the dev boards. It cleans up the eye diagram of the USB.

[image]

As far as the rest of the design, it's probably not very noise proof. If you are having problems with *random dropouts* then the design is probably susceptible to external noise corrupting packs from USB and causing dropouts OR from common mode noise from the USB grounding.

If the design is experiencing dropouts when humans are near it or touching it, then it could be an ESD issue.

It looks like the diff pair lines from the USB are run a long way across the board, it's usually best to put the processor as close to the USB port as possible to minimize the diff pair length and transmission line effects that come from long diff pairs (easier than doing math). I also see other traces that are close to the USB diff pair, which could increase cross capacitance between traces, and lead to noise coupling (or even ESD coupling).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I'm looking to re-design the board starting with the USB port and the oscillator and following it with everything else. I will include the 22 ohm resistors also in the design, that's a great tip. One question - do you think these are a big impact for USB FS also? That's only 12MHz IIRC.